# Which appcompat gradle file should be used?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I am following a tutorial which uses appcompat 22.1.1 I believe or something similar.

I am using 23.1.1 and I am getting an error, specifically

```
no resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package
```

When I try to use the @menu/menu file in my NavigationView.

Isn't it a good thing to use the latest appcompat gradle file?

What about using just 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'  with no version specified? Is that better / ok?

Edit: I just tried commenting out the menu item, now my project doesn't recognize NavigationView xml item.

Comment: Most likely, your problem has nothing to do with the `appcompat-v7` version. You probably made a mistake in following the tutorial. "Is that better / ok?" -- generally, that is a considered to be a very bad idea for serious projects.

Comment: No, the appcompat library doesn't magically provide you with @menu/menu you need.

Comment: @eriuzo I have a menu folder in my res, with a menu xml file in it. It is not being recognized

Comment: it is another issue then, perhaps post a new question with your xml and activity code

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I had was that I needed another gradle file which was

```
com.android.support:design:23.1.1
```

Arg!